# How to build an inverted map from a one-to-many list with functional programming in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Just to clarify this is what I mean by "inverted map":

```js
const foo =
  { "a": 10
  , "b": 20
  };

const foo_inverted =
  { "10": "a"
  , "20": "b"
  };
```

---

I have this object representing a file:

```js
const file =
  { id: 100
  , tags: [20, 30]
  };
```

Given a list of files I need to build a map that allows me to find all files with a given tag.

From this:

```js
const files =
  [ { id: 100
    , tags: [20, 30]
    }
  , { id: 200
    , tags: [20, 40]
    }
  ];
```

To that:

```js
{ "20": { "100": 1, "200": 1 }
, "30": { "100": 1 }
, "40": { "200": 1 }
}
```

I ended up with this code which does the job:

```js
const tag_file = (tag_id, file_id) => ({[tag_id]: {[file_id]: 1}});
const mergeDeepAll = reduce(mergeDeepRight, {});
const tag_map = compose(mergeDeepAll, lift(tag_file));
const tags_map = compose(mergeDeepAll, map(({id, tags}) => tag_map(tags, [id])));

tags_map(files);
//=> { "20": { "100": 1, "200": 1 }
//=> , "30": { "100": 1 }
//=> , "40": { "200": 1 }
//=> }
```

**Question:** am I missing any functional programming concepts that would have allowed me to express this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an a function that generates pairs `[tag, id]` for each object, using a `Array.map()` (`idByTags`). Using R.chain convert all objects to such pairs and flatten them. Group by the tag (R.head), and then map the object (R.mapObjIndexed) and count by the id (R.last):

```js
const { pipe, chain, groupBy, head, mapObjIndexed, countBy, last } = R

const idByTags = ({ id, tags }) => tags.map(tag => [tag, id])

const fn = pipe(
  chain(idByTags),
  groupBy(head),
  mapObjIndexed(countBy(last))
)

const files = [{"id":100,"tags":[20,30]},{"id":200,"tags":[20,40]}]

const result = fn(files)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh mate, that's clever ;)

Comment: Thanks. The main problem is the inversion, which is easy with vanilla, but I can't find any Ramda magic that does that. The rest is pretty obvious afterwards.

Comment: I'm gonna wait up in case some more answers come in but that's pretty good already!

Comment: I found a way a bit more terse yet still readable but your answer lead the way.

Comment: Now I'm curious. Do share.

Comment: I just need for `chain` to return each individual map and merge them together in the end: `pipe(chain(({id, tags}) => tags.map(tag => ({[tag]: {[id]: 1}}))), reduce(mergeDeepRight, {}))`

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you would need ramda, can do it with reduce and forEach

```js
const files = [{
  id: 100,
  tags: [20, 30]
}, {
  id: 200,
  tags: [20, 40]
}];

// loop over the array to make an object
const result = files.reduce((obj, file) => {
  // loop over the tags
  file.tags.forEach(
    tag =>
    obj[tag] ?  // have we seen the tag?
    obj[tag].push(file.id) :  // yes
    obj[tag] = [file.id] // no
  )
  return obj // return the object for reduce
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

AFTER YOUR EDIT

```js
const files = [{
  id: 100,
  tags: [20, 30]
}, {
  id: 200,
  tags: [20, 40]
}];

// loop over the array to make an object
const result = files.reduce((obj, file) => {
  // loop over the tags
  file.tags.forEach(
    tag => {
    obj[tag] = obj[tag] || {}  // have we seen the tag?
    obj[tag][file.id] = 1 //
  })
  return obj // return the object for reduce
}, {})

console.log(result)
```